# Is there a reason to include "set ruler" and "syntax on" in my vimrc?

Tags: vimrc

Could somebody explain, why some people add

```
set ruler
syntax on
```

to their vimrcs? Aren't these settings are already enabled by default? Is there an objective reason for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `defaults.vim` that is being sourced when you don't have your own vimrc.

It sets `syntax on` and `set ruler`.

So if you have your own vimrc and you would not set those, then you would not have syntax highlighting and a ruler.

Check `:h 'ruler'` for example:

```
'ruler' 'ru'        boolean (default off, set in |defaults.vim|)
```

And there you can follow `defaults.vim` link and read about it.

Also you can `:e $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` to see what exactly is set up when you don't have any vimrc.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know about `defaults.vim`, I simply don't see a reason to not use it.

Comment: why not to use `defaults.vim` or `ruler` + `syntax on`?

Comment: @jsv When you make a vimrc, defaults no longer applies (unless you explicitly request it). PS prefer `syntax enable`, it cooperates better.